# Popovers cannot be presented from a view which does not have a window - presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem

Tags: ios, ipad, uipopovercontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I am trying to show a UIPopover when tocuhes on the UIBarButtonItem.
I am getting this error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[UIPopoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:permittedArrowDirections:animated:]: Popovers cannot be presented from a view which does not have a window.'
```

This is my code:

```
Pop *controller;
UIPopoverController *popoverController;
controller = [[Pop alloc] initWithNibName:@"Pop" bundle:nil];
popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:controller];

[popoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny animated:YES];
```

**SOLUTION**

It works great now:

```
Pop *controller = [[Pop alloc] initWithNibName:@"Pop" bundle:nil];
UIPopoverController *popoverController = [[UIPopoverController alloc] initWithContentViewController:controller];
popoverController.delegate=self;

[popoverController presentPopoverFromBarButtonItem:sender permittedArrowDirections:UIPopoverArrowDirectionUp animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

Popovers must be presented on top of another view controller, you cannot have a popover floating in midair. Just create a view controller to present the view controller on top of.

```
UIViewController *vc = [[UIViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"ViewController" bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]];
self.window.rootViewController = vc;
[self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
```

Then create and present your popover.